# Where would one ask questions about how to use specific UX tools, like Axure or Balsamiq?

Tags: discussion

I guess it would be nice to have some technical questions on tools on UXSE, but I understand this may not be the place for it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need specialist advice on using particular tools then the best option is always going to be to go to the support / forums for those tools.

Axure certainly has such a forum: http://www.axure.com/c/forum.php

As too does Balsamiq: https://forums.balsamiq.com/

You could try Superuser as Benny suggests, but the volume of specialist users in any one particular tool is going to be limited. If you want the most accurate answer and for your question to be seen by the most number of experts in that tool, then the product support forums are always going to give you better responses. That's why those companies provide such a thing.

Comment: Increasingly, companies are moving such support to unpaid Slack forums which means good questions and answers lack a voting mechanism and disappear due to the 10K limit, drowned out by gabble.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Super User](https://superuser.com/) is the right place asking about tools, even UX tools.